# From the list of dictionaries find the largest value lengths for each key

Tags: python

```
data = [{"id": "78ab45",
         "name": "Jonh"},
        {"id": "69cd234457",
         "name": "Joe"}]
```

I want my function to return the largest value lengths for each key from all dictionaries:

```
expected_output = [
    { "size": 10, "name": "id" }, #because the length of the largest "id" value is 10
    { "size": 4, "name": "name" }, #because the length of the largest "name" value is 4
]
```

My code so far:

```
def my_func(data):
  headers_and_sizes = []
  for item in data:
     for key, value in item.items():
        headers_and_sizes.append({"size": f'{len(value)}', "name": key})
        if int(headers_and_sizes[0]["size"]) < len(value):
            headers_and_sizes[0]["size"] = len(value)
            
  return headers_and_sizes
```

Gives me this:

```
[{'size': '6', 'name': 'id'}, {'size': '4', 'name': 'name'}, {'size': '10', 'name': 'id'}, {'size': '3', 'name': 'name'}]
```

How can I fix that so that it will return the values as in `expected_output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to be updating a dictionary that stores each key mapped to the maximum length seen for that key thus far.

```py
data = [
  {
     "id": "78ab45",
     "name": "Jonh",
  },
  {
     "id": "69cd234457",
     "name": "Joe",
  },
]
key_to_max_len = {}
for datum in data:
   for key, val in datum.items():
        if key not in key_to_max_len or len(val) > key_to_max_len[key]:
            key_to_max_len[key] = len(val)
key_size_arr = [{"size": val, "name": key} for key, val in key_to_max_len.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the max value for id and name like below code, and structure the output accordingly

```
>>> data 
[{'id': '78ab45', 'name': 'Jonh'}, {'id': '69cd234457', 'name': 'Joe'}]
id  = max(map(lambda x:len(x['id']), data))
name  = max(map(lambda x:len(x['name']), data))
>>> id
10
>>> name
4
```

Comment: It's simpler as a generator expression: `max(len(d['id']) for d in data)`

Comment: @wjandrea yeah true, I am just used to lambda so provided this way

Comment: As the syntax highlighting in the code segment already indicates, `id` is a Python keyword. Better pick a different name for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to form a `tuple` with ids and names:

```
names_ids = [(eachdict['id'],eachdict['name']) for eachdict in data]
```

Format the output to have the desired shape (dictionaries), find the max length (using the `max()` function, passing it the lengths of `name`s and `id`s, using another list comprehension, inside `max()`):

```
expected_output = \
[{"size":max([len(each[0]) for each in names_ids]),"name":"id"},
 {"size":max([len(each[1]) for each in names_ids]),"name":"name"}]
```

Output will be:

```
[{'name': 'id', 'size': 10}, {'name': 'name', 'size': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following:

```
keys = list(data[0].keys())
output = {key:-1 for key in keys}
for d in data:
    for k in d.keys():
        if len(d[k]) > output[k]:
            output[k] = len(d[k])
```

Will output:

```
{'id': 10, 'name': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method here is pandas...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = [{'size': df['id'].str.len().max(), 'name':'id'},
       {'size': df['name'].str.len().max(), 'name':'name'}]
```

output:

```
[{'size': 10, 'name': 'id'}, {'size': 4, 'name': 'name'}]
```

or for addt'l names..

```
[{'size':df[col].str.len().max(), 'name':col} for col in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
data = [{"id": "78ab45",
         "name": "Jonh"},
        {"id": "69cd234457",
         "name": "Joe"}]


expected_output = [{'size': len(max([i[k] for i in data], key=len)),
                    'name': k} for k in data[0]]

print(expected_output)
```

Output:

```
[{'size': 10, 'name': 'id'},
 {'size': 4, 'name': 'name'}]
```